# Coffeescript angular lookups

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I am working on a coffeescript angular site.

I run a query and get back a list of id's

so -- /roles

```
id: 1
id: 2
id: 3
```

--- on the view -- I push these id's into a function on the controller.

$scope.addPeopleToRoles = (id)

the goal being - is it will do a look up on a person query and return their name.

so near to where I have the list of id's I now wish to make a call and fetch their name.

```
id: 1 : Mike
id: 2 : Paul
id: 3 : Jacob
```

-- my structure looks like this - but I am not getting the promises and the query success working.

```
$scope.addPeopleToRoles = (id) ->
  console.log("--->>>>>>>addPeopleToRoles", id)
  return "x"
```

^ so this works and returns everyone's name as an x.

but when I start trying to use the query and promises in coffeescript nothing happens.

//service function

```
   getPersionName = (id) ->
      DodsHttpService.get('person/:id',
        params :
          '@id' : id
      )
```

//the callback

```
$scope.addPeopleToRoles = (id) ->      
  getPersionName(id)
   .then( (response) ->
      return response.name
   )
```

I get

"[$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!"

when trying something like this - I would expect everyone's name at this point to be returned as s - but have the option to now pick the name from the response.

```
$scope.addPeopleToRoles = (id) ->
  getPersionName(id)
   .then( (response) ->
      console.log("test", response)
      return "s"
   )
```

Comment: add a `catch` after your `then` see if the request is getting some kind of error. I suspect you may need to use $q to collect/defer all the promises first and then execute all the requests in the list after you have them.

Comment: Do you have an example - its written in coffeescript so I wasn't sure

Comment: $scope.addPeopleToRoles = (id) ->
  getPersionName(id)
   .then( (response) ->
      console.log("test", response)
      return "s"
   ).catch((error) ->
      console.log error
      return "s"

Comment: Added the catch - still get an uncaught error?  main.js:19160 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []